# How much protection is provided by a partial course of COVID-19 vaccine?

Tags: immunizations, covid19

How much protection is provided by the first two injections of the three-injection Pfizer-BioNTech vaccine for toddlers? I cannot find this information anywhere. I am asking not because I plan to skip the third injection but because I would like to have a better idea of the relative risk during the period between the second and third injections.

Comment: @CVer: We don't give medical advice, but this is not asking for that - it's asking for information about how something works, which we generally tolerate as long as it's well sourced and not opinion.

Comment: This might be better asked on Medical Sciences.SE. Please note that cross-posting is not allowed, and that you're expected to present some research effort when posting.

Answer (score 1):

**Standard disclaimer: this is informational, not medical advice, and you should always consult your doctor for actual actionable medical advice.**

Multi-dose series do have some protection during the series, but not as much as the full series.  For COVID-19, there's no evidence they actively tested this during the trial; unfortunately it's not really feasible to do so (nor is it necessarily ethical to do so) in the timelines and numbers they were working with.  Thus, it's not going to be feasible to give you a *direct* answer backed by peer-reviewed (or FDA-reviewed) statistics.

However, this is not our first rodeo, immunologically speaking, and it's possible to answer your question to some degree of accuracy.  It's also possible to do post-hoc analyses to get some sense of the efficacy, even though it's not as powerful as a full study.

First thing first: recognize how long it takes for immunity to build *at all* from the first shot.  It can take up to 2 weeks to get the full immunity from the first shot; this is in particular the case with the very low dose toddler shot.  Most likely it takes less - based on T-cell replication rates, the range for COVID is likely 7 to 14 days (see for example [CD-8+ recruitment rates in infected individuals with COVID-19](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41590-021-01122-w)); but the FDA has only said within 14 days.  As such, between shots 1 and 2 there's not a ton of protection; in fact, the [post-hoc analysis submitted with the Pfizer EUA data showed a negative "protection" between shots 1 and 2](https://www.fda.gov/media/159393/download), though I'd underline that between the very small numbers and the very small window where there is any protection and the second shot in the series, this is not indicative of it not working - just that between shots 1 and 2 there isn't a ton of protection, and very few got it either way in the test during that time (single digits).

Second, there's a difference between the period between shots natural to the dose cycle, and a longer period.  The first dose, sometimes, is sufficient by itself for a period; the second dose is for several reasons.  [This Kaiser Foundation article on multi-dose vaccinations explains them well](https://www.kff.org/coronavirus-covid-19/issue-brief/what-does-a-multi-dose-series-mean-for-the-covid-19-vaccination-effort/); part of the reason is in case the first didn't generate enough of a response, and part is to increase the duration of the response.  This doesn't mean the first won't protect you for a while - it just means the second will help for longer, and make it more likely it helps at all.

Third, the time between the second dose and it being effective is much closer - thanks to the already existing pool of CD8+ and other cells that are specific to the antigens in the vaccine, you see a larger response quicker.  The post-hoc analysis showed a bit better results at that period, though I think it was somewhat hard to do because of the very variable time between dose 2 and dose 3 for the study participants - three to four months on average, and some much longer - which makes the post-hoc analysis more complex.

The closest thing to real data you can see is to view the graphs on page 41-42 of the [FDA report](https://www.fda.gov/media/159393/download); as you can see, in the younger toddlers (6-23 months) it really takes a long time before the vaccinated vs. unvaccinated numbers diverge.  In the older toddlers (2-4 years), though, the numbers diverge nearly right after the second dose would've been given, around 28 days.